# Error when using astype('float32') in Python

Tags: python

I'm newbie in python and working with this code:

```
for index, person in enumerate(people):
  print(index)
  dir_path = 'train/' + person
for img_path in os.listdir(dir_path):
  name, ext = os.path.splitext(img_path)
  if ext.lower() not in valid_images:
    continue

img_data = cv2.imread(dir_path + '/' + img_path)
# convert image to gray
img_data=cv2.cvtColor(img_data, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_data_list.append(img_data)
labels.append(index)

img_data = np.array(img_data_list)
img_data = img_data.astype('float32')
```

But when runing I get error :

`img_data = img_data.astype('float32')
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Iterate through your list:

At the end of your code you appear to be trying to change the `dtype` of the images you have stored in your list. Images read with OpenCV are naturally `numpy` arrays.

The following example should help:

```
# create a test image list
img = np.ones((60,60), dtype=np.uint8)
img_list = [img] * 4

# use a list comp to run through the images and change dtype
changed_img_list = [img.astype(np.float32) for i in img_list]
```

Comment: Yes. Thank for your help